# ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the FILE privilege(s) for this operation - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying to import a table detail into CSV using the 'OUTFILE' command (Linux box). My actual command is as below:

```
SELECT 'id','progname','contact' UNION ALL SELECT id,progname,contact  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/contact_1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM dbo.contactdetails
```

When doing so, I got the below error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the FILE privilege(s) for this operation
```

The 'tmp' folder is wide open with 777. My current username is "prod". I logged into mysql shell using this user and tried to create another super user and still for 'Access denied' permission.

When tried as root user, I am unable to login to the mysql shell at all. I see

```
access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.65.152' error
```

Honestly, only the user "prod" has some rights and I am unable to provide file permissions to this user as well. Any help on how this can be fixed?

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that fact that my backend is a remote RDS instance. The user Prod has access to that RDS instance and root user does not have access to that instance.

Comment: if prod user is the one that makes the `INTO OUTFILE` you have to provide the file rights to him. why you can access for root, is probably due to the grant for him

Comment: Correct. But even root does not have access to do that. I am trying to fix that first. When I try to do sudo myql -u root -p I get access denied error

Comment: take a look at the grant of root, usually it is reduced to localhost and not allowed for external ips

Comment: Right. Just found that root user does not have access to the RDS instance. :( should that  be set on AWS or through mysql shell?

Comment: mysql shell phpmyadmon workbench, it is always the same